# Unable to GET a value associated to div Tag <div class="name"> Value </div>

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I'm using VBA to pull a value from a nested Div Tags, as shown on below image:

[image]

HTML code:

```html
<div class="styles__SCFileModuleFooter-e6rbca-1 kUUNkj">
                            Constituída em 26-02-1962
                        </div>
```

I'm using the code Below to access class="styles__SCFileModuleFooter-e6rbca-1 kUUNkj", and pull the value "Constituída em 26-02-1962", but seems it is not capable to find that class in the loop:

```
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim htmlEle1 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmlEle2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim URL As String
Dim elemValue As String

URL = "https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/?search=500004064"


    XMLPage.Open "GET", URL, False
    XMLPage.send
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    
        
    For Each htmlEle1 In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
        Debug.Print htmlEle1.className
       If htmlEle1.className = "styles__SCFileModuleFooter-e6rbca-1 kUUNkj" Then
          
          elemValue = Trim(htmlEle1.innerText)
          If InStr(UCase$(elemValue), "CONSTITU") > 0 Then
                'Found Value
                Exit For
          End If
       End If
    Next htmlEle1
```

There are some cases where the class="styles__SCFileModuleFooter-e6rbca-1 kUUNk" appears more than once, that's the reason for the checking `If InStr(UCase$(elemValue), "CONSTITU") > 0 Then`.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not capturing what actually happens when you use a browser to make that search.

Among the various steps are the following ones:

1. You navigate to https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/?search=500004064
2. Webpage generates additional traffic
3. Amongst that additional traffic is an API POST XHR request which returns search results as JSON. That request goes to https://www.informadb.pt/Umbraco/Api/Search/Companies and includes the 500004064 identifier amongst the arguments within the post body
4. Based on the API results the browser ends up at the following URI https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/empresa/?Duns=453060832

You are not ending up at this same endpoint, where you would find the target class, as JavaScript does not run with your XMLHTTP request, and thus the additional traffic is not generated.

You might try recreating the POST request which returns the necessary `Duns` value to take you to the same endpoint. The POST request response is as follows:

```
{'TotalResults': 1,
 'NumberOfPages': 1,
 'Results': [{'Duns': '453060832',
   'Vat': '500004064',
   'Name': 'A PANIFICADORA CENTRAL EBORENSE, S.A.',
   'Address': 'BAIRRO DE NOSSA SENHORA DO CARMO,',
   'Locality': 'ÉVORA',
   'OfficeType': 'HeadOffice',
   'FoundIn': None,
   'Score': 231.72766,
   'PageUrl': '/pt/pesquisa/empresa/?Duns=453060832'}]}
```

You can see the necessary `Duns` value in the response. You would need to parse out this value possibly with a JSON parser.

However, a quick look at how the server responds to requests seems to indicate it expects to receive JSON and not simply as a string. This rules out typical XHR/WinHttp request examples you will find on the web, though you might have some luck with the implementation via https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web. However, I have found that library to constantly throw errors when I have tried using it.

With Python, for example, you can easily just POST a JSON object specifying `json = data` within the `requests.post()` call if using `requests` library.

Comment: Dear QHarr, I am very grateful for the analysis you have made on my question.
It's very well structured. I am sorry that I do not yet have sufficient knowledge to fully understand it.
For example, when you say "You might try recreating the POST request which returns the necessary 
Duns value to take you to the same endpoint.", I don't know how to accomplish it. Forguive me please.
Can I ask if you can show in practical terms, with examples in vba code, how to perform the "4 steps" that you presented so well?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @QHarr, sorry to bother you, but I need you to read my previous comment to see if theres any possibility for you to help me, please. You've said "You might try recreating the POST request which returns the necessary Duns value to take you to the same endpoint.", I don't know how to accomplish it. I noticed that substitue in my code the URL for `URL = "https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/empresa/?Duns=453060832"` It will work. Will find that <div>. Can you help please?

Comment: I was unable to get the POST working in VBA as per the penultimate point in my answer. The server is configured to expect JSON. I cannot get VBA-Web library to work in sending  JSON as required though I did add to the issues log for the maintainers. I would switch to something like Python where sending JSON is simple.

Comment: Hi @QHarr Just one more thing please. Can you tell me how can I get de JSON response that you've posted (see below please)? Can I get that response with vba code? 

`{'TotalResults': 1,  'NumberOfPages': 1,  'Results': [{'Duns': '453060832',    'Vat': '500004064',    'Name': 'A PANIFICADORA CENTRAL EBORENSE, S.A.',    'Address': 'BAIRRO DE NOSSA SENHORA DO CARMO,',    'Locality': 'ÉVORA',    'OfficeType': 'HeadOffice',    'FoundIn': None,    'Score': 231.72766,    'PageUrl': '/pt/pesquisa/empresa/?Duns=453060832'}]}`

Comment: That is the same point as my last comment. It requires sending a successful POST request with JSON body. I couldn't easily see how to get working with VBA. I checked with Python different formats and JSON was accepted.